# c++ win32 embeded 3rd party application

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, childwindow

I want to open in my main window 3rd party application, for example office, or adobe reader.

Something like this. This example is in windows forms.
[Embeded application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHpPb.jpg)

But I can use only pure c++ with winapi. Is it possible? What can I use for it. Can you give me some example?

Thanks

Comment: Unless the applications are prepared to be hosted inside another window, you cannot safely do this. None of the applications you named are prepared for this.

Comment: I am aware of MDI in windows, that allows to create child windows inside the MDI client window. But except with virtualization, I do not know how to force the top level window of an application to be a child window. Maybe you could try to create a window station or simply a desktop, and use your window as a wrapper around it. Or maybe you only need OLE which is **much** simpler even if already tricky. Currently your question (including the example) is *unclear*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by identifying the window's handle (HWND) of the application to be embedded. Then you can re-parent that window into the host window using [SetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541(v=vs.85).aspx) function of the Window API. Window handles are 32-bits so this will work even between 32/64 bits processes.

Attention should be payed however to dispatch events correctly from the host application to the embedded window (for example when re-sizing or hiding the host, the embedded window should be re-sized or hidden as well). And also position the embedded window inside the host.

[Here is an example of this approach](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18724/Hosting-exe-applications-into-a-dialog)

This may work fine with notepad, but more complex applications can manifest strange behavior when re-parented to another process window, but you can experiment.